# Computer project on GPS using linear algebra

Tags: reference-request, numerical-linear-algebra, applications

I am searching for a computer project that I once found it online but unfortunately didn't save it. The project lies within the domain of numerical linear algebra and its topic is about Global Position System (GPS).

I recall the project is about extracting the coordinates of the receiver as well as the bias of the receiver clock from the time the signal was emitted by the satellite till the time it was received. Unfortunately that's all the detail I can remember but I would be grateful if anyone who knows about this type of problem can provide me some references (articles/books) and thank you.

Comment: https://www.worldcat.org/oclc/922615642 is a book with good reviews. I found it from the project https://www.math.uri.edu/~jbaglama/classes/2018-2019/fall/mth215/project1.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much! @JackSchmidt